# Create permissions for multiple folders in a folder structure

Tags: permissions, inheritance

I'm pretty new to SharePoint. My work stores a lot of files/folders in SharePoint. I need to change folder permission on multiple sub folders (maybe 3000 sub folders). We do have a folder structure, for example:

```
Big Folder 1

Main Folder 1> Sub Folder 1, Sub Folder 2, Sub folder 3
Main Folder 2> Sub Folder 1, Sub Folder 2, Sub Folder 3

Big Folder 2
Main Folder 1> Sub Folder 1, Sub Folder 2, Sub folder 3
Main Folder 2> Sub Folder 1, Sub Folder 2, Sub Folder 3
```

So there are about 50 Big folders and within which there are many Main Folders within which there are 3 sub folders within which there are many files. These sub folders have same name across all the folders. I need everyone to be able to access the Site (which everyone has permission to at the moment) but I just want Sub Folder 3 to be restricted to say 5 specific people.

How do I go about doing this? I could do unique permissions but then I would have to go into all the `sub folders>Manage Permission>Add these five people`? And like I said there are over 3000 sub folders.

There must be an easier way to do this. Is there a script I can run that will say look for any folders named "X" and set permissions for "X". Or anyway I can achieve this?

Also, we have a SharePoint person in the company but he isn't very knowledgeable and he hosts the site. If there was a script I could run, would I have to run the script on the server/computer where the SP is being hosted? I have admin access to the SharePoint site.

Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So you could write some CSOM code in C# to set permissions on your folder structure. 
This code can be run remotely.

An example of helpful code though not a solution is here: https://samlman.wordpress.com/2015/02/28/using-the-sharepoint-2010-client-object-model-part-5/

Other approaches running Powershell for example against the SharePoint object model will require the code to be run from a server in the farm.

Answer (score 0):

```
// get a reference to the folder (this assumes path points to a valid folder)

SPFolder folder = SharePointConfiguration.Site.GetFolder(path);


// get a reference to the Sharepoint group collection

SPGroupCollection spc = SharePointConfiguration.Site.SiteGroups;


// get a reference to the group who’s permissions you want to modify for the folder above

SPGroup group = spc[groupName];


// create a role assignment from the group reference

SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment((SPPrincipal)group);


// break role inheritance for folders/files because they will be having permissions separate from their parent file/folder

folder.Item.BreakRoleInheritance(true);


// update the role assignments for the group by adding the permissionSet “TestPermissionLevel” which is a custom

// permissionset I created manually…you can easily use any of the built-in permission sets

roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(SharePointConfiguration.Site.RoleDefinitions["Test Permission Level"]);


// apply the new roleassignment to the folder.  You can do this at the listitem level if desired (i.e. this could be SPfile.Item…. instead of SPFolder.Item)

folder.Item.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);
```

Check some resources:

[Programmatically set permissions to a folder in a SharePoint list](http://sharepointserved.blogspot.com/2011/05/programmatically-set-permissions-to.html)

[How To make SharePoint document library folder unique Permission Programmatically](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/Roji.Joy/how-to-make-sharepoint-document-library-folder-unique-permission-programmatically/)

Comment: Hi can I do something like -  search folders which equals name "SNP", for each folder named SNP do, permission levvel = groupIwillCreate.